# How to parse JSON with unknown number of keys and nested JSONs, with duplicate keys

Tags: json, parsing, dynamic, google-bigquery, duplicates

I have a JSON that looks something like that one:

```
{
"condition_a":{
    "name": "aaa",
    "value": 10,
    "source": "bbb"
},
"condition_a":{
    "name": "ccc",
    "value": 20,
    "source": "ddd"
},
"condition_b":{
    "condition_c":{
        "name": "ddd",
        "value": 30,
        "source": "eee"
    },
    "condition_c":{
        "name": "fff",
        "value": 40,
        "source": "ggg"
    }
}
```

}

It has unknown number of keys, some of them hold nested JSONs within them, some of them don't. The key names are also changing and unknown.
In addition, it has duplicate keys, like condition_a is duplicated throughout the JSON but holds different values within.

I want to know how to parse this JSON onto a table that looks like this:
[image]

con_1 and con_2 are the number of levels of nested JSONs it found to be - which is also unknown!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would take the input as text string and solve this in an UDF with JavaScript. How large can this json be in size? Depending on this, the UDF can be a route.

Comment: JSON does not allow to have several key entries, or at least does not keep them. You will need to parse the text as text.

Comment: Any suggestions to solve this with text parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  ifnull(con_1, con_2) con_1,
  if(con_1 is null, null, con_2) con_2,
  name, value, source
from (
  select  kv,
    regexp_extract(norm_text, r'"([^"]+)":{(?:"[^"]+":{[^{}]+},)*' || kv || '.*}') con_1,
    trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)], '"') con_2, 
    regexp_extract(kv, r'"name": "([^"]+)"') name,
    regexp_extract(kv, r'"value": (\d+)') value,
    regexp_extract(kv, r'"source": "([^"]+)"') source,
  from your_table,
  unnest([regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(text, r'\n', ''), r'({|,)(\s+)(")', r'\1\3'), r'(")(\s+)(})', r'\1\3')]) norm_text,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(norm_text, r'"[^"]+":{\s*"name": "[^"]+",\s*"value": \d+,\s*"source": "[^"]+"\s*}')) kv
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that this approach supports this exact structure of JSON but as I said the number of nests can be unknown, as well as the number of keys and their names, meaning that this JSON can also include just one key (lets say its the first condtiion_a) and the approach should support that too.